# How does package and require work?

Tags: lua

I have a module named `load_modbus`.

This is how i require it:

```
driver_modbus   = require "lua_plugin/load_modbus";
```

Before I require it, I have these code lines:

```
-- Include Paths
package.path = package.path .. ";./usr/lua/?.lua;./usr/lua/lua_modules/?.lua";
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";./lib/?.so;./usr/lib/?.so";
```

How does the require work now?
Does it take the path which I gave to require, (`lua_plugin/load_modbus`) and place it instead of the `?` ?

Am I correct that it will search for these files:

```
./usr/lua/lua_plugin/load_modbus.lua;
./usr/lua/lua_modules/lua_plugin/load_modbus.lua

./lib/lua_plugin/load_modbus.so;
./usr/lib/lua_plugin/load_modbus.so
```

It would be nice if someone can tell me if I am correct or not. Still try to understand how it works.

Comment: Just do it: `require"foo"`  You will get an error message containing full list of directories where Lua searched the module.

Comment: But am I correct that the `?` will be replaced with what i gave to require? (lua_plugin/load_modbus)

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html

Comment: Okay, so that means im correct. Thanks

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff or you could just print package.searchpath, that has the same result but is less of a hack. `print(package.path:gsub(";", "\n"))` (gsub to make it more easily readable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Require does not assume you give it a path, but a template. This is because lua can be used on systems that don't have an actual file system. If you give it a string like "/include/?.lua" and require "test" it will replace the "?" with the string you required and try to load "/include/test.lua".

You are mostly correct with the paths it will search, but keep in mind that if you do `package.path = package.path .. <something>`  will just be appended to the standard search path, so it will not only search that path, but all the others too. If you *only* want to search one path, you'd have to do `package.path = <your search path>`

There is some more information on this at http://lua.org/manual/5.3

Consider reading that. It might also be interesting to you that lua caches the result of it's `require` calls, in case you didn't know that already.